# Routing remains same when called again in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am calling this route with this method

```
onDateChanged(event: IMyDateModel) {

    this.route.navigate(['/user/events',event.formatted]);
}
```

My events component,

```
activatedroute.params.subscribe(p => { this.date = p['date?'] });
    if (this.date) {
      this.onDateChanged();
    } else {
      this.getEvents()
    }
```

When I call it for the first time,it is triggering that component but when i call the same function again from the same route,then the component is not loaded with new values i.e previous route remains unchanged.Can anyone please help me .Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post component which handles this route?

Comment: Why do you want to call the same route again? If you want to show the changes, you can bind the view with model, and change the model will reflect the changes

Comment: I am calling it from a common component

Answer (score 0):

The component will not reload if you navigate to a route that matches the current route according to your route definitions. However, you can listen to the `params` `Observable` on the `ActivatedRoute` to be alerted when the data in the route url changes and then re-setup your component from there.

```json
{
    path: "user/events/:type",
    component: MyComponent
}
```

Navigating from `/` to `user/events/unformatted` will load MyComponent. Routing from `user/events/unformatted` to `user/events/formatted` will not load MyComponent.

Inside MyComponent you can do the following:

```js
class MyComponent {
    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
            let newFormattingType = params["type"];

            //re-setup component based on formatting type
        })
    }
}
```

You need to update your call back so the check for whether the date has changed is inside your callback and you should not have the `?` in the parameter name. Update your code to ressemble the following

```js
activatedroute.params.subscribe((p) => {
    this.date = p['date'];

    if (this.date) {
      this.onDateChanged();
    } else {
      this.getEvents();
    }
 });
```

Comment: Hi,Treddy actually I did the same.

Comment: Was the params callback called after calling navigate?

Answer (score 0):

From Angular tutorial on routing:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
    .switchMap((params: Params) => this.service.getHero(+params['id']))
    .subscribe((hero: Hero) => this.hero = hero);
}
```

For more information go to: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html